# Adamovsky's plugin pattern - How does it use init and extend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, prototype-programming

I read Milan Adamovsky's plugin pattern he has up on his blog:

http://milan.adamovsky.com/2010/02/new-jquery-plugin-pattern.html

Which begins:

```
$.fn.extend({ 
    _plugin: null, 
    jQueryInit: jQuery.fn.init 
});

$.fn.extend({
    init: function( selector, context ) {
        return jQuery.fn._plugin = new jQuery.fn.jQueryInit(selector, context);
    }
});
```

Now, to me the pattern is creating/adding two new variables to jQuery's `_plugin`, which is `null`, and `jQueryInit`, which contains the jquery `init` method (selector method).

The pattern then `extend`s again by overwriting the `$.init()` method with a new (wrapped identically) `init` method. I'm not sure what this is doing in practice.

I partially understand why the pattern has placed the `init` method into `_plugin`, as the pattern later uses it within the plugin to get the selected item/s. But wouldn't this have consequences for all other plugins? Or is the only change that its moving a copy of the `init` into a place where the plugin we are creating can be reached?

Another segment of the code I don't fully understand is at the end:

```
var _p = new MyPluginClass({});

$.fn.pluginName = _p.rc;
$.extend($.fn.pluginName.prototype,_p);
$.extend($.fn.pluginName,_p);

$.fn.pluginName.prototype

$.fn.pluginName
```

Here the pattern "extends" `$.fn` with a new variable called `pluginName` containing the plugin's `.rc` method. It then combines the entire class with the `.rc` method; isn't this just a duplication, as `extend` would bring over `.rc` anyway when it combines `$.fn.pluginName` with `_p`?

Comment: If this is the first time you have ever done a jQuery plugin, first start with a simpler tutorial: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: I have tooled around with them before and done some reading on the jquery site before i was more just trying to wrap my head around these specific things. if it was covered on that site i'll go back and re-read.

Comment: You need to understand the underlying concepts first. That pattern is a bit advanced if you're not a JS developer with some jQuery plugin development under your belt. Don't get me wrong, nothing wrong with asking, but there's concepts and techniques that would make understanding it easier if you already knew them.

Comment: ahhhh i see. generally speaking i understand whats going on in the plugin pattern. but your right i do need to read more about it. Still i'd appreciate any help if given.